# Add a try-catch with Mono Cecil 

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I am using Mono Cecil to inject Code in another Method. I want to add a Try-Catch block around my code.

So i wrote a HelloWorld.exe with a try catch block and decompiled it.

It looks like this in Reflector for the Try-Catch:

```
.try L_0001 to L_0036 catch [mscorlib]System.Exception handler L_0036 to L_003b
```

How can i inject a try catch like this via mono cecil?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Adding exception handlers with Mono.Cecil is not difficult, it just requires you to know how exception handlers are laid out in the metadata.

Let say you have the C# method:

```
static void Throw ()
{
    throw new Exception ("oups");
}
```

If you decompile it, it should look somewhat similar to this:

```
.method private static hidebysig default void Throw ()  cil managed 
{
    IL_0000:  ldstr "oups"
    IL_0005:  newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Exception::.ctor(string)
    IL_000a:  throw 
}
```

Now let say that you want to inject code in this method such as it's similar to the C# code:

```
static void Throw ()
{
    try {
        throw new Exception ("oups");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine (e);
    }
}
```

That is, you simply want to wrap the existing code in a try catch handler. You can do it easily with Cecil this way:

```
    var method = ...;
    var il = method.Body.GetILProcessor ();

    var write = il.Create (
        OpCodes.Call,
        module.Import (typeof (Console).GetMethod ("WriteLine", new [] { typeof (object)})));
    var ret = il.Create (OpCodes.Ret);
    var leave = il.Create (OpCodes.Leave, ret);

    il.InsertAfter (
        method.Body.Instructions.Last (), 
        write);

    il.InsertAfter (write, leave);
    il.InsertAfter (leave, ret);

    var handler = new ExceptionHandler (ExceptionHandlerType.Catch) {
        TryStart = method.Body.Instructions.First (),
        TryEnd = write,
        HandlerStart = write,
        HandlerEnd = ret,
        CatchType = module.Import (typeof (Exception)),
    };

    method.Body.ExceptionHandlers.Add (handler);
```

This code is manipulating the previous method to look like this:

```
.method private static hidebysig default void Throw ()  cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 1
    .try { // 0
      IL_0000:  ldstr "oups"
      IL_0005:  newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Exception::'.ctor'(string)
      IL_000a:  throw 
    } // end .try 0
    catch class [mscorlib]System.Exception { // 0
      IL_000b:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
      IL_0010:  leave IL_0015
    } // end handler 0
    IL_0015:  ret 
}
```

We're adding three new instructions: a call to Console.WriteLine, a leave to gracefully exit the catch handler, and finally (pun intended), a ret. Then we're simply creating a ExceptionHandler instance to represent a try catch handler whose try encompasses the existing body, and whose catch is the WriteLine statement.

One important thing to note is that the end instruction of a range is not contained inside the range. It's basically a [TryStart:TryEnd[ range.

Comment: Control flow isn't allowed to fall out of a catch handler like that.
ECMA-335, §12.4.2.8.1 "Exit from protected blocks, filters, or handlers cannot be accomplished via fall through." (though the Microsoft CLR doesn't seem to enforce this rule)

Comment: @Daniel, good catch, let me add the missing leave. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: thanks for this fast answer! working fine - and so easy! thank you very much!

Comment: I'm getting an InvalidProgramException, when checked with PEVerify it failed with "Return out of try block", it has ret as the last IL instruction inside the try, I have to change it to "leave LABEL" for it to work.

Comment: @wliao obviously this is just an example, and not a complete solution. You have to adjust the IL to be valid, and that includes replacing ret instructions in protected blocks to something else.